# Transaction Security Policy - Stop connectors(Data loader, Excel connectors, workbench, etc.. ) to do DML in salesforce

Tags: data-loader, security, connected-apps, dml-operations, transaction-security-policy

I got a requirement where I need to stop my users to perform the update, insert, and upset from any connector(Excel connector, workbench, data loader, etc..) even if they have access in the profile.
I know we have ApiEvent in the transaction security policy but seems like, we can only stop doing the SOQL query. But I don't want to stop login or export the records from connectors. Is there any way to stop only DML operations?

Comment: Data Loader: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338568&type=1&mode=1 . The same approach can be used for other apps that use oAuth. Workbench certainly does.

Comment: @identigral- Yes, we can control this via connected apps but not all plugins use connected apps(like google chrome extensions, excel connectors, VS Code connectors). In that case, uses are able to do DML without any control.

Comment: [LoginEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/enhanced_transaction_security_policy_types_login.htm) has enough context to prevent non-oAuth logins from users via apps. You should be able to solve this.